# CSS properties not applied to appended items in jQuery infinite scroll

Tags: jquery, css, infinite-scroll, masonry

I am using Drupal Views to load content with [this](http://www.infinite-scroll.com) infinite scrolling script into a masonry style grid of items.

It scrolls infinitely, but the appended items do not retain the CSS properties of the original items.  I am not really sure why this is happening.

Additionally, I am using a jQuery hover effect to "float" content over my images.  This is pretty straightforward code.  I can't imagine it has any affect on this issue but here it is just in case:

**jQuery for hover effect**

```
$j('div.blog-list').on(".blog-thumbs-animate").hover(function(){
    $j("img", this).stop().animate({opacity: 0.9},{queue:false,duration:75});
    $j(".bhover", this).animate({opacity: 0.9},{queue:false,duration:75});  
}, function() {
    $j("img", this).stop().animate({opacity: 1},{queue:false,duration:75});
    $j(".bhover", this).animate({opacity: 0},{queue:false,duration:75});        
});
```

**jQuery for masonry and infinite scrolling:**

```
<script>
  (function($){

    var $container = $('.blog-list');

    $container.imagesLoaded(function($){
      $container.masonry({
        itemSelector: 'div.pmason',
        columnWidth: 320
      });
    }(jQuery));

    $container.infinitescroll({
      navSelector  : '.pager',    // selector for the paged navigation 
      nextSelector : '.pager-next a',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
      itemSelector : '.blog-list .node',     // selector for all items you'll retrieve
           animate : true,
      loading: {
          finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.',
        }
      },
      // trigger Masonry as a callback
      function( newElements ) {
        // hide new items while they are loading
        var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
        // ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
        $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
          // show elems now they're ready
          $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
          $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true ); 
        });
      }
    );

  })(jQuery);
</script>
```

**Edit:  Here is the CSS**

```
.blist .pmason { width:319px; margin-right:1px; margin-bottom:1px; background:#FFF !important;}
.blist .last { margin-bottom:1px !important; margin-right:1px !important; }
.blog-thumbs-animate { position:relative !important; }
.blist .bhover { opacity:0; background:#f4f4f4; width:319px; position:absolute; bottom:0; left:0; height:100% !important; }
.bhover .inside { padding:20px; }
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: Where is the CSS ? Or the "CSS" mean to this javascript hover effect ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, well I figured it out.  My issue ended up being in the HTML, which was the one bit of code I failed to post in my original question.

For those curious, my HTML originally looked something liked this:

```
<div class="blog-list">
<div class="pmason"></div>
<div class="pmason"></div>
<div class="pmason"></div>
</div>
```

Which is correct code for any normal purpose.  But because infinite scroll appends new items inside its own  I was ending up with something more like this:

```
<div class="blog-list">
<div class="pmason"></div>
<div class="pmason"></div>
<div class="pmason"></div>
</div>
<div class="infinite-scroll">
<div class="pmason"></div>
<div class="pmason"></div>
<div class="pmason"></div>
</div>
```

Ruh-roh.  You see what's happened here?  The infinite scroll has placed itself outside my blog-list class, even though I've specified to use that class.  To get around this, I simply added an additional  wrapper on the INSIDE of blog-list so that when the infinite scroll ran it kept everything contained.

This is the final result and now it works like expected!

```
<div class="blog-list">
<div class="inner">
<div class="pmason"></div>
<div class="pmason"></div>
<div class="pmason"></div>
</div>
<div class="infinite-scroll">
<div class="pmason"></div>
<div class="pmason"></div>
<div class="pmason"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks so much to those who tried to help me.  I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know this infinite scroll plugin. But it appears that it creates new elements, and these new elements doesn't have the hover event listener.

So, I suggest you to do the hover event listener this way.

```
$j('div.blog-list').on("mouseenter",".blog-thumbs-animate", function (){

    $j("img", this).stop().animate({opacity: 0.9},{queue:false,duration:75});
    $j(".bhover", this).animate({opacity: 0.9},{queue:false,duration:75});  

}).on("mouseleave",".blog-thumbs-animate", function () {

    $j("img", this).stop().animate({opacity: 1},{queue:false,duration:75});
    $j(".bhover", this).animate({opacity: 0},{queue:false,duration:75});   

});
```

The difference between adding a event listener throught the `on` method to the `hover` method is that it do not append the event listener directly to the element, but to the selector. So even if you create new elements, this event listener will match the new elements.

More details here http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  Your code works, but unfortunately this way of doing the event listener hasn't made a difference in the way the items are displayed.  But maybe this is cleaner anyway so I may keep it in.

Comment: Could you provide us a working example of your code ? If my answer helped you in some way, please upvote.